# SQL Server wildcard in table name like in BigQuery

Tags: sql-server

In Google's BigQuery, it is possible to create tables with a sufix like:

```
my_dataset.my_table_20170601
my_dataset.my_table_20170602
my_dataset.my_table_20170603
my_dataset.my_table_20170604
...
```

This pattern can be undertood as: `my_dataset.my_table_YYYYMMDD`.

Then, it is possible to group them in a select like:

`SELECT * FROM TABLE_QUERY(my_dataset, 'REGEXP_MATCH(table_id, r"my_table_\d*")')`

It works like an union throughout the tables which names match the pattern.

I am looking for something similar in SQL Server. Is that possible by any chance?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to store the data in one table and add a date column for sorting and filtering?

Comment: Hi @JacobH, the thing is, the current day's table is going to be updated many times during the day. The number of rows may change, the values may change, so it is easier to drop the whole table and create a new one instead of checking each value for update. I mean, don't know whether this is the best approach, I am just used to it

Comment: Not without using dynamic sql, nor is it a good idea in sql.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, you mean that even using dynamic sql it is a bad idea?

Comment: I mean that mixing data (the date) in the tables structure is usually a sign of poor design.